# close the Autostart folder with a batch script / batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

I would like to close the Autostart folder on Windows 10 machine with a batch file. I have already tried to do it with:

```
@echo off
TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWSTITLE eq %DirectoryName%" /IM explorer.exe
exit
```

but it did not work. Can you help?

Comment: What did you mean by Autostart folder ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the *Autostart folder*, and how did it get opened in the first place? It's a folder on disk, which means the only way to *open it* is by viewing it in Windows Explorer or a command prompt, neither of which requires that it be closed in code.

Comment: If you press Windows-key + R and then you type shell:startup and press Enter. I want to close this folder with a batch command.